# LESS plus pixel with percentage

Tags: css, sass, less

```
height: calc(100% + 60px);
```

Above code will failed, any clue how to add extra 60px to a height of 100% using LESS?

Comment: This is valid CSS `calc`, there must be something else that causes this to fail.

Comment: How it's failing? Error, wrong calculation, style not applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LESS and CSS have a `calc` function. If you want to use the CSS calc function instead of LESS's, then you need to escape your equation. Like so:

```
height: calc(~"100% + 60px");
```

You can still pass LESS variables into this `calc` call. You need to encapsulate your variable with brackets though. Like so:

```
@padding-variable: 60px;

height: calc(~"100% + @{padding-variable}");
```

Answer (score 1):

The height in **percentage** does not work properly every time.
It will work fine if your parent have fix height (either in **px**, **pt**, **view port** unit).

Its better to use **view port** for height.
If you are not aware of it, read the following article.

https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp